# In "Pierre Menard, Author of The Quixote" is Menard an analogy for a critical lens?

Tags: symbolism, jorge-luis-borges, spanish-language

In *Pierre Menard, Author of The Quixote* by Jorge Luis Borges, the narrator of the work talks about how when he read *Don Quixote* after having been told that Pierre Menard had rewritten it with the same words, he could feel a new life coming from the page and new meaning in every word. Was this solely a satire of the ridiculousness of over-reliance on authorial intent or was it also an analogy for critical lenses?